# Java scheduleAtFixedRate stops working after 2 times

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have this code:

```
    exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.err.println("Getting messages....");
          getNewMessagesAndAddToTextArea();
      }
    }, 0, GET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

exec is in my class declared as:
    private ScheduledExecutorService exec;

I'm getting the "Getting messages...." messages 2 times and then it stops. I can't explain why. The GUI is still working. So what happened here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect `getNewMessagesAndAddToTextArea` is throwing an exception.

The first way to validate that idea is to add

```
System.err.println("Finished getting messages");
```

at the end of your `run` method. If (as I expect) you don't see that the second time, you should consider including a try/catch block which logs exceptions. You'll need to think what you want to *do* with uncaught unchecked exceptions...

Comment: Yes, you're right.. Thanks for the tip. :) Now I know in what method it happens. :)